# Extract text from web

Tags: extract, web-crawler

I'm looking for an easy toll which can crawl the web I give it to and extract all text elements from that. It will be nice if it can do: plain text, alt and title for images, header section. All of the separately if possible. The output should be somehow searchable or text files (xml) for every page it crawled. I need these text to pass them to translators.

Comment: There are plenty of web crawlers. Here are a few - [opensource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers) and [python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419235/anyone-know-of-a-good-python-based-web-crawler-that-i-could-use)

Answer (score 2):

Good old [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) can provide you most features you requested. Try `lynx -dump http://superuser.com/`, for example.

You can also use `wget` for recursively crawling the sites you need, and then process the files with various converters available, such as *htmltidy*.